# Bloquear acesso ao código fonte de um site

Tags: php, javascript

Existe alguma forma de bloquear acesso ao código fonte de um site nos navegadores firefox, chrone, Opera e Safari, impedindo acesso das seguintes formas através do botão direito do mouse,uso das teclas control+u ou acesso direto pelo menu do navegador pela opção de ver código fonte ?

Comment: perda de tempo e investimento.. no máximo, o que pode fazer é obfuscar.. isso espanta muitos curiosos, porém, quem realmente quer ler o código conseguirá decodificar de qualquer forma... por isso, é perda de tempo até mesmo para quem for manter o sistema pois para depurar um eventual erro, por exemplo, é um pesadelo...   Lembre-se que as páginas podem ser acessadas mesmo sem um browser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O código executado pelo cliente-side é acessível pelo usuário. O máximo que você pode fazer é bloquear o botão direito do mouse e as teclas através de JavaScript, mas, não pode impedir do usuário acessar o menu do navegador. Minifique o JS, para dificultar a leitura de quem tentar visualizar o fonte.

Lembre-se: As regras de negócios devem ser executadas no server-side.

Answer (score -2):

Sim é possível, você por exemplo pode utilizar algumas funções em JS.

`

```
var message="";
function clickIE() {if (document.all) {(message);return false;}}
function clickNS(e) {if
(document.layers||(document.getElementById&&!document.all)) {
if (e.which==2||e.which==3) {(message);return false;}}}
if (document.layers)
{document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);document.onmousedown=clickNS;}
else{document.onmouseup=clickNS;document.oncontextmenu=clickIE;}

document.oncontextmenu=new Function("return false")


//  F12
//==========

  document.onkeypress = function (event) {
    if (e.ctrlKey &&
        (e.keyCode === 123)) {
            // alert('not allowed');
            return false;
          }
  };


//    CTRL + u
//==============

  document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey &&
      (e.keyCode === 85)) {
          // alert('not allowed');
          return false;
        }
      };
```

`

Você pode consultar qual é o número da tecla que deseja bloquear através do site: http://www.foreui.com/articles/Key_Code_Table.htm

Comment: O código que você postou pode até funcionar, mas como alguns já disseram esse tipo de tratamento não é prático. Pois podemos desabilitar o JS da página, ou ler o site sem um navegador usando cURL por exemplo.